# How can I concat a single row dataframe to a larger one? Getting "TypeError: Expected tuple, got str" currently

Tags: python, pandas

What should be an easy issue of pd.concat a one row DF to a 789 row DF, both with the same amount of columns (columns named the same), is spitting out the error `TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`

I've tried changing to a series or dictionary instead but seemingly nothing will allow me to merge these two dataframes.

```py
episode_show_cat = pd.concat((TNG_df_byep, row_tng_date))
episode_show_cat
```

gives error:

```
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`
```

Ultimately I am trying to just add a row to a df with pd.concat

Comment: What are `TNG_df_byep` and `row_tng_date`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
episode_show_cat = pd.concat([TNG_df_byep, row_tng_date])
```

See inner brackets they are different.